# AWS ALB forwarded to all instances in Target Groups

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I'm deploying an ALB on AWS with a listener rule on port 443 to Forward to target group with two EC2 instances (Grafana with local InfluxDB for each instance).

Is it possible to forward all request to both EC2 instances?

For example, when I sent a metric to ALB I need to save it on both EC2 instances InfluxDB. Is it possible?

Comment: Likely possible, but not an out of the box config. Maybe can do something with VPC traffic mirroring, or could use a 3rd instance using the Nginx mirror modules to mirror the traffic to both hosts.

Comment: Try VPC Traffic Mirroring: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/mirror-production-traffic-to-test-environment-with-vpc-traffic-mirroring/